# How to get partially downloaded data in Alamofire when network connection was lost

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am trying to download mp3 file from server. When the network connection was lost (I turn off my wifi connection explicitly) on device, the download request is failed which is fine but i can't get the partially downloaded data.

I have found there is a property called `resumeData` in `responseData` but it always returns `nil`.

I am using `Alamofire 5.2.0`. Here is my code.

```
func startTask(urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }

    let requestDestination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = self.localFilePathForUser(url: url)!
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }

    AF.download(url, to: requestDestination)
        .validate()
        .downloadProgress { [weak self] progress in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .response { [weak self] responseData in

            switch responseData.result {

            case .success(_):
                print("Download success")

            case .failure(let error):

                print("Download failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
                print("Downloaded data: ", responseData.resumeData?.count.byteSize) // always get nil
            }
        }
}

func localFilePathForUser(url: URL) -> URL? {
    guard let userId = UserManager.shared.currentUser?.id else { return nil }
    guard let documentsPath = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first else { return nil }
    
    let newUrl = documentsPath.appendingPathComponent("\(userId)").appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent).deletingPathExtension().appendingPathExtension("mp3")
    return newUrl
}
```

Comment: `resumeData` is not the actual partial data, it's rather a (meta-)data needed to resume download, and it will only be filled if server supports resuming. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurldownload/1413244-resumedata ("Resume data is returned only if both the protocol and the server support resuming.")

Comment: alamofire docs (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#downloading-data-to-a-file) basically say the same: "If a DownloadRequest is canceled or interrupted, the underlying URLSessionDownloadTask **may** generate resume data. If this happens, the resume data can be re-used to restart the DownloadRequest where it left off."

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I just cast the `AFError` to `NSError` and retrieve the resumableData from `userInfo` using the key named `NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData`. You can also find [this](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/pausing_and_resuming_downloads) useful. Here is the working code

```
func startTask(urlString: String) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else { return }
    
    let requestDestination: DownloadRequest.Destination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = self.localFilePathForUser(url: url)!
        return (documentsURL, [.removePreviousFile])
    }
    
    AF.download(url, to: requestDestination)
        .validate()
        .downloadProgress { [weak self] progress in
            print("Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
        }
        .response { [weak self] responseData in
            
            switch responseData.result {
                
            case .success(_):
                print("Download success")
                
            case .failure(let error):
                
                print("Download failed: ", error.localizedDescription)
                
                if let resumabledata = (error as NSError).userInfo[NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData] as? Data {
                    print("Resumable Data found: ", resumabledata.count)
                } else {
                    print("No resumable Data")
                }
            }
        }
}
```